# Why is my "insert" not inserting into the database?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a WinForms application in Visual Studio using C#. When I run following code it doesn't give an error but no data is inserted in to the database table.

Code:

```
string dbfile = Properties.Settings.Default.CTMSConnectionString1;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbfile);
con.Open();

SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("Insert into Temptranstion (CustomerID, ProductName,Quantity,Price,DateTime ) Values (@CustomerID,@ProductName,@Quantity,@Price,@DateTime)", con);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@CustomerID ",comboBox1.SelectedValue);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@ProductName",textBox6.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Quantity",textBox7.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Price",textBox8.Text);
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@DateTime",DateTime.Now);
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What might the problem be?

Comment: I don't see a commit in your code.

Comment: After commit, do close your connection too.

Comment: is this query listed in a transaction somehow?

Comment: Silly question, but it can't hurt to check the simple things. Are you sure you're checking the correct database from what it says in the connection string?

Comment: + you may want to use the 'using' statement

Comment: In Desktop app, the database file will be copied under `Bin/Debug` So, I think you should have to look it into bin/Debug/Database file.

Comment: Also, can you post your connection string (password blanked out etc.) - I suspect AVD might be right (are you using AttachDBFileName?)

Comment: Use "@" in the SQL command too

Comment: Saima, did you check the return value of ExecuteNonQuery()? If it's 1, then it should have been inserted.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the most recent pattern of creating and consuming ADO.NET SQL connections and commands is inside a nested using statement, something like the following:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbfile))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    command.CommandText = "Insert into Temptranstion (CustomerID, ProductName,Quantity,Price,DateTime ) Values (@CustomerID,@ProductName,@Quantity,@Price,@DateTime)";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@CustomerID ",comboBox1.SelectedValue);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@ProductName",textBox6.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Quantity",textBox7.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Price",textBox8.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@DateTime",DateTime.Now);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

please notice that I did not run this code, I have simply refactored yours in a way that no matter what happens, connection and command are always closed and disposed.

if you are still unable to see the new record in the database different failure points could be the reason:

1) what is your connection string looking like?

2) are you checking the right target database or is the database redeployed at every execution?

3) what are the values in your input parameters?

good luck,

Davide.